# Specific link webView

Tags: android, html, internet-explorer

How to be able open link security htm link at android `WebView`?

http://reg.pnu.ac.ir/Forms/AuthenticateUser/main.htm

In this link htm university can't open any browser chrome or fire fox because only at internet explorer 6 to up level Microsoft can be open I hope help me to able open what suggestion for htm file at android web view?